# “Positiveness” of an N-dimension value

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I’m trying to work out a general way of deciding whether a set of values that describe independent characteristics of objects can be viewed as positive or negative overall.

I’ll try and use optimal cruising speed, cargo capacity and fuel consumption of a vehicle as an example. I’m going to assume these characteristics are normalised, so a value of 100 on each is equally beneficial. Also, I have a reference vehicle, so want to compare the others to it.

If I choose a candidate vehicle I can subtract candidate speed from reference speed, and mark this number on a line.  If the number is right of zero (x=0) on a conventional number line it is positive, and I’ll call that “better”.

If I use two factors such as speed and cargo capacity I can get the positive or negative difference for each characteristic and plot them in a two-dimensional chart.  I can infer that the x+y=0 line means that any benefit of one characteristic is being negated by the detriment of the other, and hence that anything above that line (using conventional axes) is “better”.  This is where I start to get hazy on things.  My working model is that the perpendicular distance from my point to that line is a reasonable measure of “overall positiveness”, and I can work that out as the length of a vector (from the (0, 0) origin) to the point multiplied by sine of the angle between the vector and the line.

If I pause and generalise what I have so far:

- Single dimension comparisons can be plotted on a line, and a point
  x=0 separates positive from negative.
- Two-dimensional comparisons can    be plotted on a plane, and a line
  x+y=0 separates positive from    negative.

So I’m expecting that for three dimensions (ie adding in fuel consumption) I can plot them in a cubic space, and a surface described by x+y+z=0 will separate positive from negative. I think I can visualise but not draw this!

And so on.

At this point I think I can formulate my question:

For a N-dimension vector is there a general way of determining how positive it is, possibly meaning its magnitude perpendicular to n1+n2+n3+…=0 and whether it falls into “positive” space?

And of course, am I asking the right question?

Comment: No, you are not asking the right question. The right question at this point is "how should I compare changes cruising speed to changes in cargo capacity to changes in fuel consumption?" These are "apples to oranges" comparisons, and the answers will differ from customer to customer. You apparently are just treating the numbers in whatever units you've used to measure them as if that were the perfect comparison. You will end up with vastly different answers for the same vehicles is you use km per second and mm$^3$ as units vs mm per hour and km$^3$ as units.

Comment: The bit saying "...these characteristics are normalised, so a value of 100 on each is equally beneficial." was to account for that.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that. You are still making an assumption that the utility is linear. That is, for example, if you increase the speed by 20%, then the utility of that speed to the user would also increase by 20%. But at least within a limited scale, that is not an unreasonable assumption.

Comment: Yes, assuming we mean the same thing I nearly added that to the previous clarification.  To make sure we are, each axis on a linear scale where  50, 100 and 200 on each is equivalent.

Comment: I was still trying to visualise this.  Once they are all of the same units and "factoring" I could just sum them.  For a N=2 dimensions case I'm considering whether the fact that for the examples [1, 1] and [1.25, 0.75] both approaches (simple addition on line or plot perpendicular to x+y = 0)  give the same result tells me that simple addition is a decent way to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I started to answer this a couple days ago, but was feeling really tired, and it has taken me till now to shake that.

The problem is actually very simple - the difficult part is what you've already presumed as handled by scaling the changes so that $100$ is equally beneficial. As for the rest:

In $n$ dimensional space, with coordinates $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$, the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = 0$$
is indeed the equation of an $n-1$ dimensional hyperplane through the origin. It is the hyperplane consisting of all directions perpendicular to the vector $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
In three dimensions, think of the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}^\mathrm T$ pointing in the direction in which $x,y,z$ increase equally, then consider the plane perpendicular to it.

For an arbitrary point $P = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, the distance from $P$ to this plane is given by $$\frac{|x_1 + \cdots + x_n|}{\sqrt n}$$
(yes, it is really that simple). But in your case, you want a directed distance with the direction where all the $x_i$ are positive to be the positive distance, so you can drop the absolute value.

Also, I don't think the $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$ scaling factor is necessary for your purposes. It sounds to me like you just need a way of comparing two different changes to figure out which is better. And for that, dividing each number by the same $\sqrt n$ factor does not change their relationship to each other. So why bother with it?

Thus I suggest just using $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n$$ as your measure of how positive a change by the $x_i$ factors will be. It is proportional to the distance from $P$ to the "equality plane", and positive in the correct direction. And it just makes sense. Improving any of the numbers by itself increases the overall value by the same amount.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for formalising what I think I was already seeing empirically.